# how to Manage UserControl dynamically on a page....?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, webusercontrol

my scenerio is like this,

i have to make a admin page ( header section )  in which i have to select single or multiple User Control from my dropdownlist ....

which will be added in the page dynamically ....

how should i do it ?

currently my idea is like this

when a some one selects and add a usercontrol from the dropdownlist list , i will add usercontrols tags in a textarea and save it in db ...

and when index pages of website is called then header section will be rendered from database and displayed ..

but how should i manage control tag which should be place on the top of the page in index.aspx while rendering it ??

please i know at some point it would be difficult to understand but i will try my best to reply if you have any query related to my question

take care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get your question correctly there is no need to store tags or anything in databse. Just the name and path of control (remember User Controls can only be loaded from same project) that you wana load.
Here is the code sample to load a user control dynamically.

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="userControlSelection" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
    onselectedindexchanged="userControlSelection_SelectedIndexChanged">
      <asp:ListItem Value="1">User Control One</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="2">User Control Two</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Panel ID="controlHolder" runat="server" ></asp:Panel>
```

And in the code behing the important part is "this.LoadControl("~/WebUserControl2.ascx");" Look at this article for more info and loading user controls [Dynamically creating User Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/30/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-2_2900_.aspx)

```
protected void userControlSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control c = null;
        if (userControlSelection.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            c = this.LoadControl("~/WebUserControl1.ascx");
        }
        else if (userControlSelection.SelectedValue == "2")
        {
            c = this.LoadControl("~/WebUserControl2.ascx");                
        }

        if (c != null)
        {
            controlHolder.Controls.Clear();
            controlHolder.Controls.Add(c);
        }
        else
        {
            //Throw some error
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps, Thanks

Comment: it worked fine, but i just changed panel to placeholder because i dont  want extra div tag which comes along panel 
but thanks it helped me